# Update rows with random value if row value is exist in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Myself new to Oracle as well as SQL,

I have developed a SQL command to update columns by random values it is working well except It is updating random values to every row in the column, I want to update the rows with if value exists. I have tried my command in 2 different ways but result still the same, my command looks like this

--type 1

```
UPDATE my_schema.table
SET  col1 =DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(8, 10)),
   Col2= DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 28)),
   Col3= DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 28)),
   Col4= DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 2));
```

--type2

```
UPDATE my_schema.table
SET col1= DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(8, 10)) where col1 IS NOT NULL,    col2= DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(10, 15)) where col2 IS NOT NULL,    col3= DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(8, 10)) where col4 IS NOT NULL;
```

Both commands updating all the rows of a columns, I have to update 15 columns in a table 
Could somebody help me how to write more efficient one or a PL/SQL procedure

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` to check the value of every column an update it only it if matches your condition:

```
update yourTable
set col1 = case
             when col1 is not null
              then DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 28))
             else null
           end,
    col2 = case
             when col2 is not null
              then DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 28))
             else null
           end
...
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for your response , But It's still updating all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

All rows are getting updated due to the missing `WHERE` clause. You may try below and flip your WHERE clause condition from `OR` to `AND` as per your need. Let me know if it works. thanks!

```
UPDATE myschema.table
   SET col1 = DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (8, 10)),
       Col2 = DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 28)),
       Col3 = DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 28)),
       Col4 = DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ('A', DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 2))
 WHERE    col1 IS NOT NULL
       OR col2 IS NOT NULL
       OR col3 IS NOT NULL
       OR col4 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Dwiwedi : Check my 2nd query, It has no effect :(

Comment: @DBA_ORACLE: your second query needs correction, you can't have `WHERE` clause like that. Its a predicate outside of your `SET`. Try once and let me know for few records. i had tried it with some null values set etc. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Dwivedi ; I tested on individual column, but no effect :( ... Could please how to appl COALESCE or NVL function on this query .

Comment: After inserting 4 rows, I had set a col value as NULL then ran the UPDATE. Only one row was updated. Tried with other combination too. Alternatively, you can write 4 different UPDATEs for those 4 columns. May be share your query, let me see what you tried.